Can't set cookies with passport google oauth
I am using Passport's GoogleAuth2.0 to login. I can login successfully but in callback function can't set any cookies.
This is my callback function after authentication :
exports.googleCallback = (req, res, next) => {
  passport.authenticate(
    'google',
    {
      failureRedirect: '/',
      successRedirect: 'http://localhost:5173/',
      session: true,
      passReqToCallback: true,
    },
    (err, user, info) => {
      if (err) return next(err); // Hata durumunu işleme
      if (!user) {
        return next(new AppError('Google authentication failed!', 401));
      }
      const userParams = {
        id: user.id,
        name: user.displayName,
        email: user.emails[0].value,
        photo: user.photos[0].value,
        // Diğer gerekli kullanıcı bilgileri
      };
      const token = signToken(userParams);
      console.log(token);
      res.cookie('googleToken', token, {
        httpOnly: true, 
        secure: false, 
        sameSite: 'None', 
        maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, 
      });
      res.redirect("http/localhost:5173/homepage");
    }
  )(req, res, next); // `passport.authenticate` 
};

I am using the function above in my router like that:
router.get(
  '/auth/google',
  passport.authenticate('google', { scope: ['profile', 'email'] })
);
router.get('/auth/google/callback', authController.googleCallback);

And there is app.js folder:
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const cors = require('cors');
const session = require('express-session');
const userRouter = require('./routes/UserRoutes.js');
const passport = require('passport');
const auth = require('./services/oauthService.js');
const AppError = require('./utils/appError.js');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.json());

app.use(
  cors({
    origin: 'http://localhost:5173', 
    credentials: true, 
  })
);

app.use(
  session({
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET || 'keyboard cat',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: {
      httpOnly: true,
      secure: false,
      sameSite: 'None',
    },
  })
);

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.use('/', userRouter);

And this is the passport config i used:
const passport = require('passport');
const GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth20').Strategy;
passport.use(
  new GoogleStrategy(
    {
      clientID: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
      callbackURL: 'http://localhost:3000/auth/google/callback',
      scope: ['profile', 'email'],
    },
    (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
      return done(null, profile);
    }
  )
);

passport.serializeUser(function (profile, done) {
  done(null, profile);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function (profile, done) {
  done(null, profile);
});

module.exports = passport;

I created a new function to check if the problem about controller, but it wasn't. In another function i set cookies succesfully. The problem only occurs in google callback function.
